What does "enough" refer to?
In Loving Vincent (2017), Armand criticizes the Boatman for not intervening when the boys
were bullying Vincent, but the Boatman defends himself by saying
Vincent chose to be with them and could have left if he wanted to.

Armand: Maybe he was there because Rene always picked up the tab.
Or, he just felt lonely and liked being around young people
who were enjoying themselves. How is it my business?

Armand moves past the Boatman, but the Boatman stops him.

Boatman: No, you‘ve had enough.

What does "enough" refer to?

Not clear from the context. Where is Armand moving to? You mentioned 'sobering up' in an earlier bit of dialogue; is he going to get another drink?

"You've had enough" is a film topos : one character feels that another is already too inebriated and intervenes to prevent them from having yet more to drink. My money is on Kate's suggestion.

Too much liquor. But please only ask questions like this if you can let us see the scene.

OP's query:

Boatman: No, you‘ve had enough..
What does "enough" refer to?

Have had enough is a phrase which means:

to want something to stop because it is annoying you:
I've had enough - I'm going home.

In the movie, "Loving Vincent", Armand is on a mission to learn more about Vincent van Gogh and the circumstances of his death.
During his conversation with the Boatman, he criticizes him for not intervening when Vincent was being bullied.
The Boatman’s response, "No, you've had enough," shows that he has reached his limit with Armand’s questioning and accusations.
By using this phrase, the Boatman  signals that he no longer wants to justify himself or continue the discussion.
Edit - 1
The full dialogue is on Page 31-32
The Boatman reaches his limit with Armand’s accusations, and the conversation ends as follows:
Boatman: “How is it my business? No, you’ve had enough.”.
Armand: “Very friendly of you, turning your back just like with Vincent. What did you do for him?”.
Boatman: “I don't hear you telling me that.”.
Armand: “Were you such a great friend?”.
Boatman: “I never said I was. There you go.”.
Armand: "Thank you.”

Wouldn't the boatman say "I've had enough" if he was the one tired of answering questions? Without reading the script or seeing the film how can you know?

@Mari-LouA I have read the script. I edited and posted the link.

Without the context, it's hard to clarify the exact meaning of the expression "No, you've had enough."
But you could guess it if you knew the expression 'have had enough (of something). This expression means you've already experienced something fully enough and don't want it anymore or can't stand it anymore.
The Boatman said "No," and this implies Aamand "should not do something because he already did something enough."
'enough' in your example is a quantitative pronoun meaning enough quantity of something: a lot of something.
